# jquery: Is there a way to run "each" iterations sequentially?

Tags: jquery, each, sequential

I have a table to manipulate. It contains rows from my database (in descending order). I
want to be able to use an array of ids, and remove the matching rows from the table. As I
remove each one, I make another call to the database to retrieve the 'next' row to show
so I can append it to the table. I have tried this two different ways - searching for the
last row in the table after the append, and having my "get the next row" return the ID
of the row that was found.

No matter which tactic I use, the "new" last id is the same, so if I have 2 elements in
my array, the same row is appended 2 times. I think I'm being burned because essentially
both of my ajax calls are run at the same time.

So basically, I want each iteration of the "each()" to run sequentially. Is there a way
to do that?

```
// get the last one in the table so we can use it for getting a replacement row
var last_sync_queue_id = enclosing_table.find('tr').last().find('input[type=checkbox]').val();

for( const idx in rows_reset )
{
    var row_that_was_reset = rows_reset[idx];

    enclosing_table.find('input[type="checkbox"]').each( function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);

        if (checkbox.val() == row_that_was_reset )
        {
            // remove the row from the table
            checkbox.closest("tr").remove();

            // and get another one to append to the end of the table
            console.log("finding 'next' row, using " + last_sync_queue_id);
            $.post( "/AjaxControlPanel/get_one_more_error_row", {'before_row': last_sync_queue_id}, function(data) {
                if ( data.success && data.html )
                {
                    enclosing_table.append(data.html);

                    // using a returned value from the "next row" function
                    last_sync_queue_id = data.new_last_sync_queue_id;
                    //
                    // OR
                    //
                    // trying to find the "new" last row in the table and getting the id from that
                    last_sync_queue_id = enclosing_table.find('tr').last().find('input[type=checkbox]').val();

                    console.log("New Last id: " + last_sync_queue_id);
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to give a feedback otherwise nobody will be motivated to answer you again. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your loop sequential you could use `async/await`, so your whole logic should be inside `async` function. Here we use an async IIFE:

```
(async () => {

    // get the last one in the table so we can use it for getting a replacement row
    const last_sync_queue_id = enclosing_table.find('tr').last().find('input[type=checkbox]').val();

    for (const idx in rows_reset) {

        const row_that_was_reset = rows_reset[idx];
        const checkboxes = enclosing_table.find('input[type="checkbox"]');

        for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

            const checkbox = $(checkboxes[i]);

            if (checkbox.val() == row_that_was_reset) {

                // remove the row from the table
                checkbox.closest("tr").remove();

                // and get another one to append to the end of the table
                console.log("finding 'next' row, using " + last_sync_queue_id);

                const data = await $.post("/AjaxControlPanel/get_one_more_error_row", { 'before_row': last_sync_queue_id });

                if (data.success && data.html) {
                    enclosing_table.append(data.html);

                    // using a returned value from the "next row" function
                    last_sync_queue_id = data.new_last_sync_queue_id;
                    //
                    // OR
                    //
                    // trying to find the "new" last row in the table and getting the id from that
                    last_sync_queue_id = enclosing_table.find('tr').last().find('input[type=checkbox]').val();

                    console.log("New Last id: " + last_sync_queue_id);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: Ok, so one answer is to not use each. Let me try that out

Comment: Ok, that worked, thanks I have to work out some other algorithmic issues, but my loop is all set now.

Comment: @AndyWallace you are welcome. We could write some function like Promise.series to execute callbacks in a queue, but that would be more cumbersome. I think a `for` loop with `break` looks pretty simple and good.